# The image set of the operator $\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^{n-1}}$, for sequences with $a_1=0$ and $a_n\in\{-1,0,1\},\forall n\geq 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, real-numbers, gamma-function

For a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ with $a_1=0$ and $a_k\in\{-1,0,1\}$ for all $k\geq 2$ one can to prove the convergence of 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^{n-1}},\tag{1}$$ where $\Gamma(s)$ is the Gamma function, for example using [1] 
$$ \left| \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^{n-1}} \right|\ \leq 1.$$

**Definition.** On the set of our sequences
$$\mathcal{S}= \left\{a= (a_n)_{n\geq 1}: a_1=0, \forall k\geq 2 \text{ with }a_k\in\{-1,0,1\}\right\} \tag{2}$$
we define $\mathcal{F}:\mathcal{S}\to [-\xi,\xi]$, where $\xi=\sum_{n=2}^\infty 1\cdot\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^{n-1}}$ to be $$\mathcal{F}(a)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^{n-1}}.\tag{3}$$

> **Question.** Is $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{S})=[-\xi,\xi]$? In other words, my question is if we can to prove that our operator is surjective:
>
> $\qquad$*For each fixed* $x^{*}\in[-\xi,\xi]$ *there exists a sequence* $a^{*}\in\mathcal{S}$ *such that* $\mathcal{F}(a^*)=x^*$.
>
> **Many thanks.**

This is a table containing examples of an approximation of $\mathcal{F}(a)$ for the corresponding  sequences for $n\geq 2$ defined as $a_n=1$, $a_n=n\text{ mod } 2$, $a_n=(-1)^{n-1}$, $a_n=\mu(n)$ the Möbius function and $\lambda(n)$ the Liouville function.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \hfill a_n, n\geq 2\hfill & \hfill\sum_{n=2}^{50}a_n\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^{n-1}}\hfill \\ \hline 
\\ \qquad 1 &   \quad \approx 0.87985\\ 
\\ \qquad n\text{ mod} 2 &   \quad \approx 0.26784\\
\\ \qquad (-1)^{n-1} &   \quad \approx -0.34417\\
\\ \qquad \mu(n) &   \quad \approx -0.75109\\
\\ \qquad \lambda(n) &   \quad \approx -0.65887
\end{array}$$

### References:

[1] Juan-Bosco Romero Márquez, *Problem 1651*, Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 75, No. 3 (June, 2002).

Comment: I've deleted previous comment since now is without context, but since previous comment included a congratulations message I add here it one more time: *congratulations for the diamond* @JackD'Aurizio

Answer (score 0):

Possibly useful hint:

$\Gamma(n)/n^{n-1}
=n!/n^n
\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}/e^n
$.

Comment: This is relevant for sure. Now, given that $2<e<3$, is the operator $\mathcal{F}$ surjective or $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{S})$ is a Cantor set with measure zero?

Comment: Almost looks like the representation of numbers in base $e$.

Comment: Many thanks, was a curiosity when I was calculating with these series of cited form (also was doing calculations to get the asymptotic behaviour of  different series as $\sum_{n=2}^N (p_n\text{ mod }4)\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^{n-1}}$, where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime number), when I wondered what about the image of my operator.